# Why i am getting multiple element appended while clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just adding a `span` as parent of text selection. i do 2 ways one using clicking on button another on by pop-up button (on select will appear)

When i click the pop-up button multiple times, i am getting appended as much of (multiple times) spans as parent of my selection.

how to fix this? any one help me?

myjs:

```
 function selHTML() {
    var nNd = document.createElement("span");
    var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    w.surroundContents(nNd);
    $(nNd).addClass('highlight');
}

$("#addText").on('click',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selHTML());
});

$("div.content").mouseup(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (!range.collapsed) {
        var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = bounds.left + ((bounds.right - bounds.left - $(".savetooltipAll").outerWidth()) / 2);
        var y = bounds.top - $(".savetooltipAll").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".savetooltipAll").css("top", (y+(bounds.top)) + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").css("left",x + 'px');
        $(".savetooltipAll").show();
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(selHTML()); //it calls multiple times...
        });
    } else {
        $(".savetooltipAll").hide();
    }
});

$("div.content").mousedown(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection();
    console.log(range.type);
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wx9b1r/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're (re)registering the `.click` handler every time the `.mouseup` handler is invoked.

Just do it once, outside of the handler.

Aldo, don't write `$()` around the call to `selHTML()` - it's invoking jQuery but will have no effect has you're discarding the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
          selHTML(); //it won't call multiple times... :)
      });

$("div.content").mouseup(function(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (!range.collapsed) {
      var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = bounds.left + ((bounds.right - bounds.left - $(".savetooltipAll").outerWidth()) / 2);
      var y = bounds.top - $(".savetooltipAll").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop();

      $(".savetooltipAll").css("top", (y+(bounds.top)) + 'px');
      $(".savetooltipAll").css("left",x + 'px');
      $(".savetooltipAll").show();

  } else {
      $(".savetooltipAll").hide();
  }
});
```